# not able to find RouteConfig.cs and global.asax in Razor web site VS2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I just upgraded from VS2013 to VS2017 express edition and I am trying to create a MVC application. I choose web site ASP.NET (Razor v3).

I cannot find in the project structure where is the file RouteConfig neither the global asax file. When I deploy the test site, everything is working correctly.
Did I miss something ? or is there any changes regarding VS2017 ?

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rqyk.png)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are talking about a website not a webapp which can be seen in you attachment.

An ASP.NET site can run without the global.asax file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307821/what-alternatives-are-there-to-using-global-asax) is a question which talks about alternatives of global.asax file.

For `Route.config` you can add a file and add routes in it