# What is the default startup page for ASP.net Projects

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I have an ASP.net project I'm working on (1st time in ASP.net) however I'm curious to know how I would find which page is the page Visual Studio launches when I start debugging.  Each time I search for this answer all the results simply tell you how to SET the startup page and not what the startup page actually IS. Basically - "What is the entry point"?

Currently my 'Start Action' when viewing the Project Properties is set to 'Current Page'.  While I realize I can set a specific page or 'Start URL' I'm wondering what  does 'Current Page' refer to?  Basically I'm looking to know where I find the first line of code that is run when I begin debugging.

My initial thought was that it is looking for an aspx file named `default.aspx` but since my project has two of these files named `default.aspx` I guess it's pointing to the one residing with my other project files that sit at the root of my project.

Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: You can find the Default page by checking your routes. If you truly have an MVC app you should have somewhere a static class called RouteConfig. This will have a route setup with a controller/action pair.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is two question you are asking.

Firstly, where is the entry point for your MVC application? Well your entry point for debugging MVC application would be `Application_Start` in **Global.asax.cs** file

```
protected void Application_Start()
{

}
```

Secondly, the Start Action is Visual Studio enables you to specify what happens when you run your application.

- Current Page – Enables you to run the page currently open for editing in Visual Studio.
- Specific Page – Enables you to set a particular page to run. You can set the page here or you can right-click a page in the Solution Explorer window and select the menu option Set As Start Page.
- Start External Program – Enables you to run an external program.
- Start URL – Enables you to request a URL. This option is typically used when building a Web Services application.
- Don’t open a page – Enables you to do nothing.

You can change the start page to a particular page. For example, if you want to request the URL `/Blog/Show/23` when your application starts, then you can enter this URL into the Specific Page input field.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused as to what an MVC ASP.net application is.  I say this due to my not seeing any files named `Global.asax.cs`.  In fact I don't have any files with asax extensions.  My Project does however have a Web.config file.  I found this link that seems to be closer to my existing setup:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307821/what-alternatives-are-there-to-using-global-asax.

Comment: I answered in MVC as the question was tagged as MVC, if this is not the case let me know which? If it is a default MVC application you should have a Gloabal.asax file. You can test it yourself by creating a new web application and selecting MVC.

Comment: Good to know.  Since I did not create the project I'm not sure how to see in Visual Studio what the original project was that was created for the project I'm now working on.  I know that it's ASP.net due to it using the namespaces System.Web.  I thought the project was MVC due to it organizing it's code into the MVC architecture.  I see ViewModels folder and a Models folder.  All of the data that is being gathered by the code behind written in c# is being bound to from the aspx aka ASP.net code.  Is my assumption wrong?  It looks like MVC.

Comment: Under References check if you have `System.Web.MVC`. Since you had mentioned `Default.aspx` I believe it is a WebForm project.

Comment: I do not have that reference.  I guess maybe that this project was created as an ASP.net Web Forms.